# How sending email from same domain cause third parties to receive cookies

Tags: email, cookies

I recently read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338332/is-email-from-do-not-replystackoverflow-email-legit

> If we'd add a CNAME to a third party under the stackoverflow.com
>   domain, they'd receive all our users cookies, which some sites are OK
>   with, but we aren't.

On the answer by [m0sa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa) it was said that using same domain as the website to send email would compromise the cookies to third parties. How is it so? And what is this CNAME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNAME is like a domain alias, for example if you make *email.stackoverflow.com* a CNAME pointing to *evil.com*, anyone trying to access *email.stackoverflow.com* would actually access whatever server *evil.com* is pointing to. However, as far as the browser is concerned, it still thinks it's accessing *email.stackoverflow.com*, and will happily send all cookies set by the root domain, which could include sensitive session tokens.

By using a totally different domain (instead of a subdomain) they mitigate this risk and prevent their third-party e-mail/newsletter provider from getting user's session cookies.

The browser could send cookies if the user either explicitly clicks any links to the subdomain or if the e-mail is in HTML format and links to resources on that domain like images.

Comment: thanks, one more question, who would be the `third party`?

Comment: @Ruchan a newsletter provider - MailChimp, SendGrid, etc.